# how to disable scrollbar on jupyterlab markdown cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Somehow some (not all!) of the markdown cells in a jupyter-lab notebook
acquired vertical scrollbars.

I can't figure out how to turn off the scrollbar and display the whole cell?
What setting controls this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a hack to avoid the problem:
wrap the cell contents in a `<div style="height:5cm;">`
and fiddle with the height to make the result come out right...

I'd love a better solution, though. Anybody?